# Is it possible to point a Google Cloud DNS entry to a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: dns, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Could I use a reference or link to my Google Compute Engine host's logical name, instead of `173.255.x.x.` in:

```
{
    "additions": [
        {
            "kind": "dns#resourceRecordSet",
            "name": "compute-engine-host.domain.com.",
            "rrdatas": [
                "173.255.x.x."
            ],
            "ttl": 60,
            "type": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible yet, but I'll see if we can get it on the list of things to build.

Until then, you *should* be able to use the [Cloud DNS API's Changes.create](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/api/v1beta1/changes/create) method to have your GCE machine add/update a DNS record when it boots up...